# How do I apply an if statement condition to every element on an arraylist?

Tags: java, if-statement, arraylist

Basically I want to know how to apply an if condition to every element of an arraylist.
    Here's my code.

```
   System.out.println("Type positive integers less than 40: ");

    ArrayList<Integer> inRay = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (sc.hasNext())
    {
        inRay.add(sc.nextInt());
    }

    //this is where the problem starts//

    int i;
    if (inRay.get(i) > 40)
    {
        System.out.println("You had one job.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

I would like to apply an if condition where if a value in the array list is over 40, it exits.

Comment: It would appear you've never heard of a `for` loop.

Comment: ...or any other loop. Maybe start [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_loop_control.htm).

Comment: Do you want to apply the if check as it is entered or once all input has been entered?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line where you are declaring 'i' with a for loop that starts from 0 and goes up to iRay.size().

```
for(int i=0; i<iRay.size(); i++)
```

In this for loop, the portion before the first semi-colon, declare and initialize a counter variable to 0. After the first semi-colon is the condition up to which the loop should repeat, and after the second semi-colon, is the increment of the counter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the `ArrayList` like this:

```
for (int i : inRay)
    if (i > 40) {
        System.out.println("You had one job.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

In general, if you want to do something for every element of an array list, do this:

```
for (Type t : list) {
    // do something involving t
}
```

You need the actual type of the array list elements instead of `Type`.